# Excel Variable Range Name

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula

I'm having a problem on linking a sheet using a variable/cell number on range which is a link from the other sheet. 
e.g.,

Sheet1- contains data in row
Data i'm taking is from row 4, column O
linking to a different excel sheet

Sheet2- problem on linking

```
='[Sheet1.xlsx]SUMMARY '!$O$4
```

the link above works fine, but error occur when i change this value "$O$4"
using a variable or cell value

```
='[Sheet1.xlsx]SUMMARY '!$O$ "A1"
```

where A1 = 4

```
='[Sheet1.xlsx]SUMMARY '!$O$ "Rnum"
```

Rnum using defined name refers to value of 4

so doing multiple sheets by changing Rnum's value or A1 cell to 5
will change the result of all links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=offset('[Sheet1.xlsx]SUMMARY!$O$1,4,1)`

Comment: this only links the val from A1 on sheet1

Comment: ok... try `=offset('[Sheet1.xlsx]SUMMARY!$O$1,4,1)`

Where you are moving 4 rows and 1 column.... change those values as required. Or make em variables

Comment: thanks finally got it to work on the offset and using a variable as 4